# Why is the page empty?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the following script which uses `JSCaman`, but, get an empty page. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="caman.full.min.js">
</script>

<script 
type="text/javascript">
Caman("#myCanvas", "Desktop/javascript/abder.jpg", function()
 {
  this.brightness(5).render();
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: Because `"Desktop/javascript/abder.jpg"` is not a valid URL? Try with an image hosted online and tell us what you get.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics Sorry I'm new to JavaScript. How can I check the console? Thanks

Comment: @blex I used a URL, but the same. Thanks

Comment: F12 brings up the developer tools. The console is right there.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome, right click on page, and choose console tab, then paste your code:

```
Caman("#myCanvas", "Desktop/javascript/abder.jpg", function()
 {
  this.brightness(5).render();
 });
```

hit enter then the console will tell you what's wrong, cheers!